# GDP type: WDA, NSA, SA

Tags: gdp

What are the acronyms for? SA, WDA, NSA. I was able to find WDA: written down allowance, but I am not sure is correct and how is applicable to GDP.

[image]

Comment: It might help if you explained where you have seen this image.

Comment: Bloomberg terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SA = seasonally adjusted

WDA = working day adjusted

NSA = not seasonally adjusted